# Removing the first 29 chars of every line not printing correct result

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at Python trying to write my first script.
I've got a text file with multiple lines and need to eventually extract a piece of timecode from the list. 
The list looks like this:

```
010  AX       V     C        01:01:26:10 01:01:27:17 01:00:08:19 01:00:10:02
* FROM CLIP NAME: movie1.mov

011  AX       V     C        01:01:30:19 01:01:32:19 01:00:10:02 01:00:12:02
* FROM CLIP NAME: movie2.mov

012  AX       V     C        01:00:15:01 01:00:17:13 01:00:12:02 01:00:14:14
* FROM CLIP NAME: movie3.mov
```

etc.

My first objective is to grab the first timecode displayed.

I know that the first timecode on every line starts at character #29 and ends at character #40 so I started by trying to remove the first 29 characters but anytime it prints it's not starting at the right character.

```
timecode = []                               # Declaring my empty list.
with open ('test.edl', 'rt') as myfile:     # Opening the edl.
    for myline in myfile:                   # For each line in the file,
        print(myline.lstrip(myline[:29]))   # strip first 29 chars
```

Rather than stripping the first 29 chars, I'm receiving this in return:

```
:01:26:10 01:01:27:17 01:00:08:19 01:00:10:02

movie1.mov


:01:30:19 01:01:32:19 01:00:10:02 01:00:12:02

movie2.mov


:00:15:01 01:00:17:13 01:00:12:02 01:00:14:14

movie3.mov
```

Even when I change `print(myline.lstrip(myline[:29]))` to `[:25]`, it prints the lines the same way.

When I'm using `[:20]` it's giving me a better result but it's still incorrect.

`C        01:00:15:01 01:00:17:13 01:00:12:02 01:00:14:14`

I've been searching relentlessly to figure out what I'm doing wrong here but no luck.. Again, complete beginner here so I'm sorry if this is plain stupidity.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`lstrip` does not do what you expect it to. `myline.lstrip(myline[:29])` will remove characters from the left of `myline` as long as they are found *anywhere* in `myline[:29]`, i.e. the first `29` characters of `myline`. Therefore you are certainly removing the first `29` characters, but also `01` at the beginning of the  of the time code, because `0` and `1` appear in the first `29` characters of `myline`. (The `0` is removed anyway, because you miscalculated the bound, `myline[:29]` would include the `29`th character).

You can select all characters, starting from the `29`th character with `myline[29:]`.

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick, thank you kindly for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

you want to start at 29, not end at 29. also, `lstrip()` will take off more.
try replacing your 4th line with this:

```py
print(myline[29:])
```

Comment: Thank you David, works much better! Appreciate you took the time to reply!